# how to get a client id from ajax tab container

Tags: asp.net

i didn't get id from ajax tabcontainer

HERE code id need to get a id from tab_container how to do !!!!!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       function my()
       {
           var con = document.getElementById("TabContainer1").value;
           alert(con);
       }         
</script>


 <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Height="100%" Width="50%">
            <asp:TabPanel ID="tabpnl1" runat="server" HeaderText="Role Master">
              <ContentTemplate>                  

                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="my()"  /> 

              </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
```

its shows undefined

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The information you provided is not sufficient .

Comment: where is TabContainer1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get TabContainer1 in javascript you need to change logic of your javascript function

instead of

```
function my()
       {
           var con = document.getElementById("TabContainer1").value;
           alert(con);
       }
```

try using

```
 function my()
       {
           var con = document.getElementById("<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>");
           alert(con);
       }
```

As runtime while loading element in dom its ID will be changed. So instead of using static id as "TabContainer1" you can get ClientID which will be rendered at DOM. 
Also value will not be work I guess as its container so its better to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`.

or alternative you can change your html tag

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Height="100%" Width="50%" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

I have added `ClientIDMode="Static"` so it will use "TabContainer1" in DOM as static id will be generated. In this case, you do not need to change your javascript code.

Hope this help